# Dynamic option list based on a choice of type

Tags: php, mysql

What i did is i write first of 3 select option choice based on a content of a database, and its look like this:

```
<select name="job" >
<option value=""></option>
<?php $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT jobs FROM database order by jobs"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '<option value="'.$row['jobs'].'">'.$row['jobs'].'</option>';}?>
</select>
```

The structure of database is like this:

```
id------jobs-----stage---location
1--------1--------2-------africa
2--------1--------2--------america
3--------1--------3-------china
4--------2--------2--------india
```

I am trying to make select option based on a first select option
Example:
If a user select 1 from joobs then in another option list to list stages for joobs based on 1 and on third option list to list locations based on a second option list of stage if its 2 or 3.

I have tried to google it but all i can find ist to much complicated querys with javascripts and ajax, didnt worked for me :/
Thank you very much!

Comment: show us what u tried in ajax. This can be done in ajax easily.

Comment: This one: http://coursesweb.net/ajax/multiple-select-dropdown-list-ajax_t But its to complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first select give `class` or `id`, and then

```
<script>
$(document).on("change","#jobs",function () {
    var keyword = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: "keyword=" + keyword,
            success: function (html) {
                $("id or class of second dropdown").html(html).show();
            }
        });        
});
</srcipt>
```

check [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html), it will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I am sory to ask but is there something else easier from this example?

Comment: This is very simple. try this, i ll help you.

Comment: to hard for me..<select name="jobs" >
<option value=""></option>
<?php $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT jobs FROM database order by jobs"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '<option value="'.$row['jobs'].'">'.$row['jobs'].'</option>';}?>
</select>




<option value=""></option>
<?php 

if selected from name="job"
job as = chois
run choise  $sql = "SELECT stage FROM database where job = 'chois' order by stage"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '<option value="'.$row['stage'].'">'.$row['stage'].'</option>';}?>
</select>

Comment: first part is correct. just follow the instructions, i ll tel you

Comment: add id="jobs" for first select box.

Comment: `code` <select name="job" id="jobs">
<option value=""></option>
<?php $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT jobs FROM database order by jobs"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '<option value="'.$row['jobs'].'">'.$row['jobs'].'</option>';}?>
</select>`code`

Comment: <select name="job" id="stage">
<option value=""></option>
<?php 

if resulta from jobs = job_selected
job_selected as $job_selected
//run mysql 

$sql = "SELECT stage FROM database where jobs='job_selected' order by stage"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '<option value="'.$row['stage'].'">'.$row['stage'].'</option>';}?>
</select> Niranjan N Raju they dont allow me to extended discussions in comments :/ Could you please provide me some code or to continue on some chat ?